# How does a computer perform computations?

Tags: memory

I'm reading about computers and it all seems a bit complicated to me. I come across this sentence:

> To perform useful computation, we need to irreversibly change distinguishable states of memory cell(s)

What does this exactly mean? I personally don't exactly know what 'distinguishable states' and 'memory cells' are, and a google search doesn't seem to illuminate me much.

If I had to guess I'd say they mean that to perform useful computation, you need to change the state of a bit from 1 to 0 and from 0 to 1. But I'm not too sure, so my questions are:

- Is my interpretation right? Does the author mean that in order to compute you need to change the 0/1's (i.e. states) of bits (i.e. memory cells)?
- If not, what does he mean? And in particular, what is a 'distinguishable state' and what is a memory cell?

This is the source: http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2012/ph250/kumar1/

Comment: It would help to know the source of this quote.  In modern computers a human should consider anything below Y voltage as a low and anything above it as a High.  In reality there is a voltage state where its niether a high or a low.  A `undistinguishable state` would describe that event.

Comment: @Ramhound You are correct, I added the source in my post.

Comment: Also worth remembering is that 0 and 1 are abstract concepts that people use, not the actual distinguishable state. Base 2 is a simple concept, hence its use when we talk about computer operations.

Comment: @AthomSfere  - I am not sure abstract is the correct word to describe the reasons a voltage low is a `0` and voltage high is a `1`.  While any character could have been replaced there are very good reasons those "written language characters` were choosen.

Comment: @Ramhound 0 and 1 what? Milliamp, amp, hz? In binary notation 1 generally means some threshold was met and is represented with a 1. I would call that an abstraction of what is really happening. I in now way disagree that it is a good abstraction, but I think the best way to understand what is going on is to remember it is just an abstraction, just like Oliver's coin abstraction.

Comment: @AthomSfere - The unit would be binary a numerical value connected to the voltage levels.

Comment: @Ramhound I think we are more or less saying the same thing here... But yes, binary is a simple analogy of how the various components perform logic and storage.

Comment: @user30117: about computers and computation, please have a look at the way Feynman describe computers: [Richard Feynman Computer Heuristics Lecture - YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKWGGDXe5MA‎). In a nutshell: A computer does NOT compute. It handles data. It's just a kind of "filing clerk". And it's really, really dumb (and therefore Fast, as it is so dumb its behavior was possible to reproduce with eletricity and components)

Comment: I have a really tough time agreeing that what a binary adder does is not "computation".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Memory cell

A memory cell can be anything that can *keep* a certain state. Of course, in the end we mean something like RAM, but it could also be a coin.

A coin has two sides, heads and tails. And if you flip it, it will stay like that, until you flip it again.

### Distinguishable states

You want the states of your memory cell to be distinguishable from each other. As noted above, the coin has two sides, heads and tails, thus, the two sides are distinguishable from each other because they are different.

We need to have this property so that we can assign meaning to the states. One state can *mean* 0 the other can mean 1.

Comment: Thank you, but in the specific case of computation with a computer, am I correct when I say that the author means 'bit' with 'memory cell' and that the 'distinguishable states' are the states of a bit, namely 0 or 1?

Comment: The example Oliver used is good.  Because the same coin could be flipped and land on its side.  This `undistinguishable state` is neither heads or tails.  The memory cell needs to be designed to handle which state it would use if this were to happen.  There computers are binary and not trinary and it deals with electrons and the inability to keep 100% of them contained without some leakage.  A binary system allows for all the leakage ( within reason ) and it won't effect another state.

Comment: @user30117: Well, I think the author is trying to explain the concept of computation in a more abstract way. The fact that our computers use the binary system with 2 states is just one implementation of the explained concept. And the memory cell is closer to a capacitor, a "bit" is just a unit of measurement.

Comment: @user30117 - The author is indeed speaking about a High voltage and Low voltage. A computer can be design with more then 2 states. It does not have to be 0 or 1.  I will be honest.  I wouldn't read to much into what this user wrote.  Its not even clear that PH250 is a graduate class.  **I hope your not using it as a source for your own classwork**

Comment: @user30117: In this context, as the author is writing about the limits of Moore's Law (the idea that computing power doubles over a given time period), yes, I guess he's primarily talking about bits in our binary system (he even mentions it later on). The author wants to show the physical limits to Moore's Law and, thus, also showing the limits of computing power we *can* reach given our current understanding of physics.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I believe Moore's law is actually about transistor density that doubles, not necessarily computing power (I think there's a difference, but you're the expert). I accepted your answer, it was helpful (thanks), but do you think the author's statement (when taking in account he's talking about bit) is actually somewhat true?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not using it for anything, as I'm still a high schooler. But I am just interested in Moore's law and when it will collapse and such. But I am kind of confused as to why his stuff is not correct, I always thought computers computed using bits with 2 states? I know about the theoretical possibility of qubits (with 1 state), but I am talking about current 'normal' computers, if you will.

Comment: @user30117 - There are only 2 states high or low.  `High` and `Low` are represented by `1` and `0`.  In reality the voltage levels can between these values.  Hardware must take this fact into account.  Electrons like to move to other paths with less resistance.  If enough electrons move to another path the low state on that path turns into a high.  I would use another source to understand Moore's Law.

Comment: @user30117: True, transistor density doesn't necessarily imply computing power. The statement by the author as quoted in your question is most certainly true. The rest of the paper is far outside my capabilities to judge. Could be more suited for [cs.se].